# <m-down> in vim

Tags: vim, nnoremap

In OSX Lion, in vim, I try use this nnoremap.

```
nnoremap <m-Down> :cnext<cr>zvzz
nnoremap <m-Up> :cprevious<cr>zvzz
```

[vimrc from sjl](https://github.com/sjl/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/.vimrc#L207)

I added the nnoremap to ~/.vimrc, but when I press `ALT-Down` nothing happening.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Vim in Terminal.app, the Alt key doesn't work by default. You must enable it in its preferences, it's a checkbox labeled "Use option as meta key" in the settings panel.

But you could use MacVim which understands the Alt key by default.

But you could use `<leader><Down>` and `<leader><Up>` which are going to work everywhere, `:help mapleader`.